# What is the etymology of "adventus?"

Tags: etymology, latin, roots

What is the complete root etymology of the Latin word "adventus?"

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adventus#Etymology_1

Comment: @lemontree. The wiki-etymology (advenio + tus) is wrong. It is  not from the present tense  advenio, but from the stem adven-.

Comment: @fdb Okay, don't know enough about Latin to judge this. I was just linking this to show that the OP could very easily have come up with a first hint on the answer to his question himself and could then have asked for clarification more specifically (like the Wiki entry being wrong in some point, in case he could've figured that out) rather than asking a that general and easily googleable question, aside from the fact that this language-specific question is off-topic anyway.

Comment: @lemontree. Look at my answer. It is not as simple as it looks. For real etymologies you have to consult specialised academic books; google does not necessarily have the answer.

Comment: @fdb Okay, then you are right about the non-triviality of the question then. Still, the question is off-topic ;)

Comment: @lemontree Why is it off topic? Single languages/words are on topic on this site, as long as the question is linguistically relevant (and not about usage for example).

Comment: **To close voters:** I'd like to remind you that the close reason for language specific questions states: *"...unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage."* I don't see how this question is concerned about usage in any way. It's about etymology, that's within the scope of linguistics and therefore of this site. Granted, the OP could have done more research on it before asking, but it's still on topic.

Answer (score 2):

It is from the preverb ad and the stem of the verb venio, namely ven-, Indo-European *gʷm-. Actually, adventus is two different words: the perfect passive participle adventus (genitive adventi), from *gʷm-to-, like Sanskrit gata-, and the noun adventus (genitive adventūs), from *gʷem-tu-, like Skt gantu-. The two forms coalesce in Latin in the nominative singular.

Answer (score 0):

It comes is from PIE forms

***a̯ed*** meaning "to"

and

***ğemtus*** meaning "act of coming" (root ğem-, it is also the source for English word "come")

Comment: *gʷm-to- means “having come” (participle). *gʷm-tu- means “coming” (noun). You have mixed up the two words.

Comment: @fdb according to Lubotsky ***ğmtos*** meant "coming", but he also gives the form ***ğemtus*** with the same meaning. According to Wikitionary, ***ğmtos*** meant "passable", so there are different reconstructions.

Comment: Yes, *gʷm-to- is also “act of coming” in PIE,  but Latin adventus, -ūs cannot derive from it, but only from *gʷem-tu-

Comment: @fdb ah, I see, the long u matters. Fair enough.

Comment: @fdb But he gives the form with a root vowel. Any arguments why there should be no vowel?

Comment: It is mainly because Skt gata- has zero-grade stem, but gantu- has full grade.